# Focus next control on enter - in overridden KeyUp

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010

I have my custom class that extends TEdit:

```
  TMyTextEdit = class (TEdit)
   private
     fFocusNextOnEnter: Boolean;
   public
    procedure KeyUp(var Key: Word; Shift :TShiftState); override;
   published
     property FocusNextOnExnter: Boolean read fFocusNextOnEnter
                                 write fFocusNextOnEnter default false;
  end;
```

In The KeyUp procedure I do:

```
procedure TMyTextEdit.KeyUp(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  inherited;

  if FocusNextOnExnter then
    if Key = VK_RETURN then 
      SelectNext(Self as TWinControl, True, false);
end;
```

But it isn't moving focus to the next control. I tried to

```
if Key = VK_RETURN then
      Key := VK_TAB;
```

but it isn't working either. What am I missing?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[`SelectNext`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Controls.TWinControl.SelectNext) selects next sibling child control, ie. you need to call it on your edit's parent:

```
type
  THackWinControl = class(TWinControl);

if Key = VK_RETURN then
  if Assigned(Parent) then
    THackWinControl(Parent).SelectNext(Self, True, False);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it is not working like a tab key - it always move focus to a first control on a form

Comment: It should move to the next control based on the `TabOrder` and `TabStop` properties of other sibling controls.

Comment: @JustMe, I just tested TOndrej's code (because I was going to post the same thing, but he was faster). It works just fine, I've got 3 `TYourTextEdit`'s on my form and focus circulates from one to the other, just as you'd expect.

Comment: Try passing `True` as the last parameter (`CheckTabStop`).

Comment: What if the parent is one container of many on the form. Would this code just cycle around the controls in that container or would it reach out to the first control of the next container?

Comment: @Tondrej I'm sorry, it's working like expected, must have some junk from old project :)

Comment: @David To be able to jump to controls in a different container you have to replace both occurrences of `Parent` with `GetParentForm(Self)`.

Answer (score 6):

Here's the PostMessage approach (uses Messages) for the record :)

```
procedure TMyEdit.KeyUp(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin
  inherited;
  if FocusNextOnEnter then
    if Key = VK_RETURN then begin
      PostMessage(GetParentForm(Self).Handle, wm_NextDlgCtl, Ord((ssShift in Shift)), 0);
      Key := 0;
    end;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
procedure TMyEdit.KeyUp(var Key: Word; Shift: TShiftState);
begin

  inherited;

  if FocusNextOnExnter and Focused and (Key = VK_RETURN) then 

  begin

    Perform(CM_DIALOGKEY, VK_TAB, 0);

    Key := 0;

  end;

end;
```

Comment: It's also strongly suggested to add some description to the answers as code might be not self-descriptive for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The THackWinControl can be avoided, and to make it nice:

```
SelectNext(ActiveControl as TWinControl, True, ssShift in Shift);
```

Problem is it still pull down combobox choices.

I'm working on that.